# OpenXML Landscape on certain sections

Tags: c#, openxml, wordprocessingml

How do you set certain sections (what type of sections should I be using?) to landscape or portrait?

I am attempting to create sections that have the following section properties (see code below) and then set that section to landscape or portrait respectively. However, when I use this code and create break paragraphs the code generates a blank page in landscape.

```
    public static SectionProperties PageOrientationPortrait()
    {
        SectionProperties sectionProperties2 = new SectionProperties();
        PageSize pageSize = new PageSize()
        {
            Width = (UInt32Value)12240U,
            Height = (UInt32Value)15840U,
            Orient = PageOrientationValues.Portrait
        };
        PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin()
        {
            Top = 1440,
            Right = (UInt32Value)1440U,
            Bottom = 1440,
            Left = (UInt32Value)1440U,
            Header = (UInt32Value)720U,
            Footer = (UInt32Value)720U,
            Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U
        };
        Columns columns = new Columns() { Space = "720" };
        DocGrid docGrid = new DocGrid() { LinePitch = 360 };
        sectionProperties2.Append(pageSize, pageMargin, columns, docGrid);
        return sectionProperties2;
    }
    public static SectionProperties PageOrientationLandScape()
    {
        SectionProperties sectionProperties = new SectionProperties();
        PageSize pageSize = new PageSize()
        {
            Width = (UInt32Value)15840U,
            Height = (UInt32Value)12240U,
            Orient = PageOrientationValues.Landscape
        };
        PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin()
        {
            Top = 1440,
            Right = (UInt32Value)1440U,
            Bottom = 1440,
            Left = (UInt32Value)1440U,
            Header = (UInt32Value)720U,
            Footer = (UInt32Value)720U,
            Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U
        };
        Columns columns = new Columns() { Space = "720" };
        DocGrid docGrid = new DocGrid() { LinePitch = 360 };
        sectionProperties.Append(pageSize, pageMargin, columns, docGrid);
        return sectionProperties;
    }


    public static Paragraph GenerateSectionBreakParagraph()
    {
        Paragraph paragraph232 = new Paragraph();

        ParagraphProperties paragraphProperties220 = new ParagraphProperties();

        SectionProperties sectionProperties1 = new SectionProperties();
        SectionType sectionType1 = new SectionType() { Val = SectionMarkValues.NextPage };

        sectionProperties1.Append(sectionType1);

        paragraphProperties220.Append(sectionProperties1);

        paragraph232.Append(paragraphProperties220);

        return paragraph232;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you wish to create a standard section in a WordProcessing document you first need to create an empty [Paragraph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc798098(v%3Doffice.14)) element and an empty [ParagraphProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc866762(v%3doffice.14)) element. Then you can create a [SectionProperties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2010/cc844633(v%3Doffice.14)) element with the desired properties as shown below:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Will create a section properties
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="orientation">The wanted orientation (landscape or portrai)</param>
    /// <returns>A section properties element</returns>
    public static SectionProperties CreateSectionProperties(PageOrientationValues orientation)
    {
        // create the section properties
        SectionProperties properties = new SectionProperties();
        // create the height and width
        UInt32Value height = orientation == (PageOrientationValues.Portrait) ? 16839U : 11907U;
        UInt32Value width = orientation != (PageOrientationValues.Portrait) ? 16839U : 11907U;
        // create the page size and insert the wanted orientation
        PageSize pageSize = new PageSize()
        {
            Width = width,
            Height = height,
            Code = (UInt16Value)9U,
            // insert the orientation
            Orient = orientation };
        // create the page margin
        PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin()
        {
            Top = 1417,
            Right = (UInt32Value)1417U,
            Bottom = 1417,
            Left = (UInt32Value)1417U,
            Header = (UInt32Value)708U,
            Footer = (UInt32Value)708U,
            Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U
        };
        Columns columns = new Columns() { Space = "720" };
        DocGrid docGrid = new DocGrid() { LinePitch = 360 };
        // appen the page size and margin
        properties.Append(pageSize, pageMargin, columns, docGrid);
        return properties;
    }
```

When creating a section properties element with a certain orientation it is important that you adjust the height and the width of the [PageSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.pagesize?view=openxml-2.8.1) element accordingly. Otherwise the pages within the section will be rendered incorrectly (if you render a landscape section with portrait height and width the section will appear to be a portrait).

When we are done creating the sectionproperties all we need to do is to append the section properties to the empty paragraphproperties and then append the paragraphproperties to the paragraph.

Using this function we can create a word document having different orientated sections with the console program below:

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Wordprocessing;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;

namespace ChangeDocVariable
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using(WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Create(@"path to document", WordprocessingDocumentType.Document))
            {
                // Create the maindocument part
                MainDocumentPart maindDocomentPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
                // add the document
                Document document = maindDocomentPart.Document = new Document();
                // add the bdoy
                Body body = document.Body = new Body();

                // insert a set of sections
                // To insert a section we need to add a paragraph
                // which contains paragaph properties
                // which holds the section properties
                Paragraph firstSection = new Paragraph();
                ParagraphProperties firstSectionProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
                firstSectionProperties.Append(CreateSectionProperties(PageOrientationValues.Portrait));
                firstSection.Append(firstSectionProperties);

                Paragraph secondSection = new Paragraph();
                ParagraphProperties secondSectionProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
                secondSectionProperties.Append(CreateSectionProperties(PageOrientationValues.Landscape));
                secondSection.Append(secondSectionProperties);

                Paragraph thirdSection = new Paragraph();
                ParagraphProperties thirdSectionProperties = new ParagraphProperties();
                thirdSectionProperties.Append(CreateSectionProperties(PageOrientationValues.Portrait));
                thirdSection.Append(thirdSectionProperties);

                body.Append(firstSection, secondSection, thirdSection);

                // for the last section we can directly add a section properties
                body.Append(CreateSectionProperties(PageOrientationValues.Landscape));
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Will create a section properties
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="orientation">The wanted orientation (landscape or portrai)</param>
        /// <returns>A section properties element</returns>
        public static SectionProperties CreateSectionProperties(PageOrientationValues orientation)
        {
            // create the section properties
            SectionProperties properties = new SectionProperties();
            // create the height and width
            UInt32Value height = orientation == (PageOrientationValues.Portrait) ? 16839U : 11907U;
            UInt32Value width = orientation != (PageOrientationValues.Portrait) ? 16839U : 11907U;
            // create the page size and insert the wanted orientation
            PageSize pageSize = new PageSize()
            {
                Width = width,
                Height = height,
                Code = (UInt16Value)9U,
                // insert the orientation
                Orient = orientation };
            // create the page margin
            PageMargin pageMargin = new PageMargin()
            {
                Top = 1417,
                Right = (UInt32Value)1417U,
                Bottom = 1417,
                Left = (UInt32Value)1417U,
                Header = (UInt32Value)708U,
                Footer = (UInt32Value)708U,
                Gutter = (UInt32Value)0U
            };
            Columns columns = new Columns() { Space = "720" };
            DocGrid docGrid = new DocGrid() { LinePitch = 360 };
            // appen the page size and margin
            properties.Append(pageSize, pageMargin, columns, docGrid);
            return properties;
        }
    }
}
```

This will create a document with four sections. The last SectionProrties can be directly added to the body of the document itself.